# Find k such that the function $f(x)=|x|^3$ is $C^{k}$ but not $C^{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I've been working on this for a while, it is on a practice sheet so there are no answers. A proof would be appreciated!

Find *k* such that the function $f(x)=|x|^3$ is $C^{k}$ but not $C^{k+1}$

Cheers

Comment: Have you graphed it?  Its derivative?  Its second derivative?  Insight can come from pictures.

Comment: Try splitting up the function into positive and negative components. Ie $f(x)=x^3$ for positive $x$ and $f(x)=-x^3$ for negative $x$. When do the derivatives of these stop matching at the origin?

Comment: They stop matching at $C{^3}$

Comment: Ok. What does this mean for $f$ in relation to $C^3$? Is it in $C^3$? Is it is $C^1$ and $C^2$ (what is the derivative at $0$)?

Comment: it is in $C^{2}$ and does not exist at $C^{3}$